# R: how to extract sentences using regular expressions

Tags: r

I would like to extract sentences from a paragraph if the sentences contains a specified keyword. For example if I have a bunch of sentences (defined by their full stops)I would like to extract the sentence that contains the keyword "school"

```
data: "sam goes to school. sam comes home and study. sam is a good boy." 
keyword: "school"
Desired Result: "sam goes to school"
```

I understand that you could extract the word and their position using "str_locate_all" and "str_extract_all"

for example

```
str_extract_all("sam goes to school. sam comes home and study. sam is a good boy." regex("school", multiline = TRUE))
```

Can someone help me to extract the sentence containing the keyword. Or extract 10 leading or trailing words following the keyword. 
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `strsplit` to split the sentences and then with `grep` get the desired output

```
grep("school", unlist(strsplit(str1, '(?<=\\.)\\s+', 
                                  perl=TRUE)), value=TRUE)
#[1] "sam goes to school."
```

If we don't want the `.` at the end of the sentence,

```
grep("school", unlist(strsplit(str1, "\\.\\s+")), value=TRUE)
#[1] "sam goes to school"
```

#### Update

If we need to extract two words before the "school"

```
library(stringr)
str_trim(str_extract_all(str1, "(\\w+\\s+){2}(?:school)")[[1]])
#[1] "goes to school"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "sam goes to school. sam comes home and study. sam is a good boy."
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Is there any way we can specify the number of words that gets extracted (leading or trailing )

Comment: @rrodrigorn0  Not sure I understand your comment.  Can you be a bit more specific with an example.

Comment: I would like to know how I could extract a specific number of words before and after the specified keyword. For example can I just extract 2 words before the words "school" and after if any words exists. In this case I would get a output of "goes to school". Thanks again for the support